# How can I see my ping in Fortnite BR?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Sometimes I feel like I am rubber banding/lagging on Fortnite, but I am unable to find a setting in the main menu for additional stats/net stats.

How can I see my ping in Fortnite BR?

Comment: There was an option to enable "Net debug stats" in the HUD section of the options but from what I'm reading online it's been removed since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to settings > game > matchmaking region. Your current ping is displayed in milliseconds next to the server location.

[image: screenshot]

This setting may not exist in the console and mobile versions.

Comment: Is the `game` option only visible while in a game? I do not have that setting in my main menu options.

Comment: @Childishforlife: No, it is visible at all times. Updated the answer with a screenshot. Reply if you still have issues.

Comment: Is there anyway to see this **in game** though? The current option requires me to move out of the match to a menu screen.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder you can't see it **in game**. You can see it in the lobby, though. Usually, your fps says your ping - higher fps = less ping.

Answer (score 0):

Just open up the menu, press R2 to open the HUD menu and turn on "net debug statistics" which should be 2nd from the bottom. This was done on PS4.